# How to find the phases of $i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $-1$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

[In this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxyBa.png), it says that the phase of the complex number $i$ is $\pi/2$ and $-1$ has phase $\pi$.

We use this formula to find the phase: $\varphi(z)=\text{arctan}\left(\frac{\text{Im}(z)}{\text{Re}(z)}\right)$

Then, the phase of $i$ should be $\text{arctan}(1/0)$, which is undefined, and $-1$ should be $\text{arctan}(0/1)=0$. So why it says otherwise in the example?

Comment: Your formula for the phase does not cover all cases. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part Yours is for the case that the real part is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z\in\Bbb C$ and $z=x+yi$, with $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then, if you want to write $z$ as $\rho\bigl(\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i\bigr)$, then you will have $\rho\cos(\varphi)=x$ and $\rho\sin(\varphi)=y$. Therefore, if $x\ne0$, you will have$$\frac yx=\frac{\rho\sin(\varphi)}{\rho\cos(\varphi)}=\tan(\varphi).$$But this was done under the assumption that $x\ne0$. If $x=0$, then\begin{align}z&=yi\\&=\begin{cases}|y|\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)i=|y|\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)i\right)&\text{ if }y\geqslant0\\-|y|\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)i=-|y|\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)i\right)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{align}Besides, note that $\tan(\varphi)=\frac yx$ is *not* the same thing as $\varphi=\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't quite get it, what is the phase. As I understood the phase is the angle that is inside sin, hence i is pi/2. But then how do you find the phase for -1?

Comment: The phase $\varphi$ of a complex number $z$ is a number $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $z$ can be written as $\rho\bigl(\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i\bigr)$, for some $\rho\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 1):

This formula does not quite work because it returns a number in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. That is the range of $\arctan$.

The phase/argument of a non-zero complex number is a number (i.e. angle expressed in radians) in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$. Or some authors say it's in $[-\pi, \pi)$. In any case the length of the interval should be $2\pi$ so $\arctan$ does not quite work in all cases.